# how i can remove elements from list with out using remove method?

Tags: java, collections

how can we remove elements from list with out using `remove()` method in java?? using collections concept.

normally i know to remove elements using `remove()`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create an empty array list with an initial capacity
    ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(5);

    // use add() method to add values in the list
    arrlist.add("G");
    arrlist.add("E");
    arrlist.add("F");
    arrlist.add("M");


    System.out.println("Size of list: " + arrlist.size());

    // let us print all the values available in list
    for (String value : arrlist) {
      System.out.println("Value = " + value);
    }  

    // Removes element "E"
    arrlist.remove("E");

    System.out.println("Now, Size of list: " + arrlist.size());

    // let us print all the values available in list
    for (String value : arrlist) {
      System.out.println("Value = " + value);
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you *want* to do that? Give us more context about what meaningful result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your first question should have been, how to add element without `add()` method. I mean, your question isn't making any sense at all, at least to me.

Comment: Use `Iterator#remove` or create a new list and add all elements you but not the one you want to remove xD but this is like scratching your right ear with your left hand

Comment: This is a good game. Are you looking for the old fashioned Iterator#remove() method?

Comment: there are many ways..!but we want to know why you need this..?

Comment: First question what are your intentions for doing that. Second, internally ArrayList in java uses Object[] so based on what you want to do you can have your own implementation of ArrayList with your modified remove method.

Answer (score 0):

I'll play, but this is something of a cheat because the obvious implementation of clear(), the one in AbstractCollection, uses the Iterator remove() method internally. If this is not what is wanted, maybe the objections will clarify the question.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a",
        "b", "c", "d" }));
    System.out.println(data);
    funnyRemove(data, 2);
    System.out.println(data);
  }

  public static <T> void funnyRemove(List<T> list, int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= list.size()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("index out of range");
    }
    List<T> part1 = new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(0, index));
    List<T> part2 = new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(index + 1, list.size()));
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(part1);
    list.addAll(part2);
  }

}
```